# Expected number of "ones" in the rolls

Tags: probability

A game is played by repeatedly rolling a fair die until the die turns up "six" four times, then the game stops.

Given that the last game lasted greater than or equal to 20 rolls, find the expected number of "ones" in the rolls.

Comment: What have you tried?  Can you find the chance that you get four sixes before twenty rolls?  That will give you a rescaling factor for removing those cases.

Comment: Can you also find the expected number of ones if the game lasts, say, 30 rolls?  How about $n$ rolls?

Comment: I have found that basically what the problem is asking is "how many ones will you get if you roll a dice until you get four sixes". I believe the E(X) of the number of rolls would be k/p until you get four sixes since the distribution follows a negative binomial. After that, I am not sure how to derive how many ones we will see.

Comment: You know there are four sixes.  All the rest of the rolls are equally distributed between the other numbers.